# What ways are there to get deterministic identifier for running instances of same program?

Tags: operating-system

One computer is running N instances of same program. Those instances communicate with each other (e.g. via sockets), and they need identifiers. What methods are there to get deterministic identifier for each instance from operating system?

With deterministic I mean that instance can during its lifetime ask from operating system something and operating system should always return same answer to same instance (so instance does not store its identifier, but will instead asks for it when needed).

Process/Thread id is one solution, but are there others?

Environment is limited to Windows/Mac/Linux server.

Comment: Do identifiers need to persist between runs? If not, I am not clear why you couldn't just generate a guid and use that.

Comment: The process ID?